# Proof of Pythagora's equality by Separable Hilbert space and Gram-Schmidt

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to prove this:

\begin{equation}
\Bigg\| \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} f_{j} \Bigg\|^{2} = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \Bigg\| f_{j} \Bigg\|^{2}
\end{equation}

where $u_{1}, ..., u_{n} \in H$ are mutuallly orthogonal i.e. $\langle u_{i}, u_{j} \rangle = 0$ for all $i \neq j$.

### My proposal just showing that Hilbert space is separable:

A Hilbert space $H$ is separable if $H$ contains a countable dense subset $\{h_{n}\}$.
For every $x \in H$ and every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an integer $N_{\epsilon}$ and scalars $\{a_{n}\}$ such that

\begin{equation}
\Bigg\| x - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} a_{n} h_{n} \Bigg\| < \epsilon \quad for \, N > N_{\epsilon},
\end{equation}
where Gram-Schmidt provides $H$'s orthonormal space from a countable dense subset, giving a dense subspace of $H$.
This provides the completeness (orthonormal sets) which the Pythagora's equlity states. $\square$

I wonder if this is sufficient for a rigorous proof.

Sources

- Basics Facts About Hilbert spaces [here](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~pauld/M645/BasicHS.pdf)

I think here is one good [proof](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/Func/Beamer-Proofs/HWG5-2.pdf). 
However, it is using vectors so I think if it is suitable for functional analysis.

---

How can you prove more rigorously Pythagora's equality?

Answer (score 3):

Let $c = a+b$ with $\langle a,b \rangle = 0$. It follow immediatly by the definition of a scalar product that

$$\|c\|^2 = \langle c,c\rangle = \langle a+b,a+b\rangle = \langle a,a\rangle + \langle b,a\rangle +\langle a,b\rangle+\langle b,b\rangle$$

$$= \|a\|^2+ 0+0+\|b\|^2$$

Hence $\|c\|^2 = \|a\|^2+ \|b\|^2$

Comment: Yes, intuitively like this. I made the body of the question clearer also for the definition of the inner product in in this case.